# DynamoDb Alarm on Put

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm trying to create an alarm when an item is Put into a dynamo db (not read from or updated)

Is this possible? The documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/MonitoringDynamoDB.html#dynamodb-metric-dimensions) seems to suggest that I can create an alarm on `GlobalSecondaryIndexName PutItem`

However when I go to create an alarm, there are only 2 metrics available:
Provisi

- ProvisionedReadCapacityUnits
- ProvisionedWriteCapacityUnits

Am I totally misunderstanding how to create this alarm?

Answer (score 1):

go to CloudWatch -> Metrics -> DynamoDB -> Operation -> PutItem
and choose the table you want to monitor, from there you can do any cloudwatch operation you want :)